# P5.JS 3d how to pre-rendering

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, p5.js

My project is to complete our Computer Science Final Project. Our teacher forced us to use the P5 framework to write games on the web for the Final Project. I don't want to write a 2D game because it is so easy.
So I tried to use P5.js to imitate Minecraft to write a game as my Final Project (our teacher said that I can imitate the existing game modes and ideas, just to ensure that the code is written by myself.)

Because the single-thread performance of P5.js is too poor, and the block does not support multiple textures, I can only use a plane to draw the block, but this causes my FPS to be seriously reduced. Drawing 10 * 10 blocks will reduce the FPS to 80 about.
I want to ask whether p5.js can pre-render frames, or how to directly operate webgl?
I can only use p5.js because our teacher does not allow our final project to use other frameworks to write web games.

*The FPS in the following display is the number of frames per second of the draw function of p5. Since P5 can only draw graphics in Draw, and this is a serial drawing, when the drawing function takes too long, it will reduce the FPS. I The Minecraft to be imitated may require a field of view of at least 50x50-80x80 blocks, which is not a block underground.*

**If I have 9x9 blocks, I will get 144FPS:**

[image]

**If I have 20x20 I will get 88FPS:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Stephen Chen! And welcome to StackOverflow. Please rephrase your question to make it clearer. Also, we don't need so much context/bragging :p Have a good day!

Comment: I don't know P5.js at all but [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-voxel-geometry.html) shows how to optimize minecraft style 3D. Maybe you can apply the same ideas to p5.js.